# Get the count variable outside the linq query context

Tags: c#, linq

How can I assign the count to totalCases variable?

I just wonder whether I can do something like the following,

```
 let count = DbContext.Set<CaseAction>().Count(c => c.IsToDo == isToDo) into totalCases
```

Is the variable declared with let can be accessed outside the context of the query?

```
 public PagedList GetCatTaskByCompanyId(int companyId, int? isToDo, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
            {
                var totalCases = 200;
                var caseModels = (from casemodel in DbContext.Set<CaseAction>()
                                  where casemodel.IsToDo == isToDo
                                  let count = DbContext.Set<CaseAction>().Count(c => c.IsToDo == isToDo)
                                  orderby casemodel.TaskCreatedOn descending
                                  select new CaseDetailsModel
                                  {
                                      TaskId = casemodel.Id,
                                      CompanyId = companyId,
                                      Title = casemodel.Title,
                                      TaskTypeId = casemodel.TaskTypeId,
                                      TaskTypeGroupId = casemodel.TaskTypeGroupId,
                                      CaseSubject = casemodel.TaskName,
                                      CurrentComment = casemodel.CurrentComment,
                                      IsPinned = casemodel.Pinned,
                                      CurrentActionTypeId = casemodel.CurrentActionTypeId,
                                      CurrentActionTypeName = casemodel.CurrentActionTypeName,
                                      NextActionDueOn = casemodel.NextActionDueOn,
                                      CurrentActionCreatedOn = casemodel.CurrentActionCreatedOn,
                                      CurrentActionAssignedTo = casemodel.AssignedToStaffName,
                                      NextActionTypeName = casemodel.NextActionTypeName,
                                      ActionCount = casemodel.ActionCount
                                  }).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                                    .Take(pageSize)
                                    .ToList();

                return new PagedList
                {
                    Data = caseModels,
                    PageIndex = pageIndex,
                    PageSize = pageSize,
                    Count = totalCases
                };
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `let` line and also remove `totalCases`.

Simply call `Count()`, passing in your predicate, to your list when you return your data.

I.E

```
 return new PagedList
                {
                    Data = caseModels,
                    PageIndex = pageIndex,
                    PageSize = pageSize,
                    Count = caseModels.Count(c => c.IsToDo == isToDo)
                };
```